# Unable to call ASPX function through JQuery without any data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, function, call

I am trying to call my aspx function using jquery but I'm unable to call it. I have added a breakpoint to my code but that breakpoint never goes off, meaning that the function is never called. Following is my code below:

jquery:

```
update();

function update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Codes.aspx/testfunction',
        method: 'post',
        success: function () { alert("yay"); },
        failure: function () { alert("no"); }
    });
}
```

aspx:

```
public static void testfunction()
{
    // A break point in visual studio here
}
```

The success function is always called but the code never breaks at the breakpoint.

However, I wish to populate my data in db in the aspx function.

Let me know where I am wrong.

**Whole Jquery function:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Add_Code").click(function () {                      //Empty code validation
                var new_code = $("#<%=new_code.ClientID%>").val();
                // alert(new_code);
                if (new_code == "") {
                    $("#validation_code").show();
                    $("#error_div").addClass("has-error");
                }
                else if (new_code != "") {
                    update();

                    function update() {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "Codes.aspx/testfunction",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: "Sent from update function",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            //async: true,
                            //cache: false,
                            success: function (response) { alert(response.d); },
                            failure: function (response) { alert("no "+response.d); }
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            })
```

**Updated Code:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string testfunction(string response)
{
    string abc = response;
    return abc + "and server";
}
```

Comment: Can you try removing the 'static' keyword from the 'testfunction'?

Comment: @ajawad987 i tried but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the ASPX function did not work, so I created a new Web Service and called it from there. It worked smoothly. Thankyou Gagan Deep for your time and explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Paste this inside the script tag. add your if condition for checking the null value

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Add_Code").click(function () {                //Empty code validation

            update();                
            return false;
        });

        });
    function update() {
        var obj = {};
        obj.response = "Sent from update Function";
        $.ajax({
            url: "default2.aspx/testfunction",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            //async: true,
            //cache: false,
            success: function (response) { alert(response.d); },
            failure: function (response) { alert("no " + response.d); }
        });
        }

</script>
```

Comment: I have already added this web method before the testfunction. It still wont work.

Comment: <div class="modal-footer">

<button id="Add_Code" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">/button>

<button id="Close_tab" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>

Comment: Are you calling this Javascript function inside Document.ready?? or binding it to the button. i don't see the code for biding.

Comment: I am calling it from the inside of the document ready function from the script.

Comment: I tried your method but i always got undefined in the javascript popup.

Comment: I have tried with placing my code inside document.ready as well and it works correctly. paste all markup here.

Comment: I have added my whole document ready function. please see above.